Why does my Apache Beam Dataflow pipeline not write to BigQuery?
I'm working on an Apache Beam pipeline that processes data and writes it to BigQuery. The pipeline works perfectly when using the DirectRunner, but when I switch to the DataflowRunner, it completes without errors or warnings but doesn't insert any rows into BigQuery. Additionally, I see large leftover files in the temporary directory of my Cloud Storage bucket (gs://my-bucket/temp/bq_load/...), and no data appears in the target table.
Here’s the pipeline structure:
worker_options.sdk_container_image = '...'

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    processed_data = (
        p
        | "ReadFiles" >> beam.Create(FILE_LIST)
        | "ProcessFiles" >> beam.ParDo(ProcessAvroFileDoFn())
        | "WriteToBigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table=f"{PROJECT_ID}:{DATASET_ID}.{TABLE_ID}",
            schema=BQ_SCHEMA,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED
        )
    )


Key Observations:

The pipeline succeeds with the DirectRunner, writing data to BigQuery without any issues.
With the DataflowRunner, the pipeline completes without errors or warnings, but: No rows are written to BigQuery & large temporary files remain in the bucket (e.g., bq_load/...).
The data being processed is valid NDJSON.
The BigQuery schema matches the data structure.

What I’ve Tried:

Inspecting the leftover temp files, I downloaded the temp file and verified that it contains valid NDJSON rows. Manually uploading this file to BigQuery using the bq load command works fine.

Testing with other datasets:
I tried many different inputs, but the issue persists.

Checking Dataflow logs:
I looked at the logs in the Dataflow Monitoring Console but found no errors or warnings.

Different service account: a service account with insufficient dataflow permissions throws an error. It therefore seems unlikely that the issue is in permissions for the workers.


I saw one other thread about this (Can't make apache beam write outputs to bigquery when using DataflowRunner) but nothing got resolved there.

The Dataflow worker needs proper permissions to write to your BigQuery dataset. Please double-check that the service account used by your Dataflow job has the "BigQuery Data Editor" role on the target dataset.

If after running your pipeline you don't see the records in the table, one possibility is that there were errors.  In your example, you don't seem to be looking for errors.  Try and instrument your code to look for errors in execution of WriteToBigQuery ... see this question ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628883/why-writetobigquery-doesnt-show-any-errors

@Kolban there are no errors in the logs which is very puzzling, don't understand why it's silently failing

@XQHu I tried running it with a different service account and got an error "Missing permissions: dataflow.workItems.lease, ...." . So it does throw errors if the permissions aren't there. Granted these were only dataflow permissions and not bigquery, but still.

If there are no errors being reported then puzzle deepens.  What we should likely do next  is look at the statistics in the Dataflow console.  For the job, there should be something that declares the elements processed for the WriteToBigQuery transform.  Let's validate that it isn't 0.  What I'm wondering is if the pipeline is not feeding any upstream records.  Another thought, if there are no errors look really closely at the table you THINK you are appending to ... make sure that what you are looking at and what Dataflow is writing to are the same.

Have you checked the worker logs? https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging#view_logs

The WriteToBigQuery PTransform returns only something in case of an error (see source code). Have you looked at the value of processed_data when running in Dataflow?

The problem turned out to be that I defined the google Storage Client object globally in my script.
When I refactored the code to be modular, and put the storage client & bucket initialization in the setup function of my DoFn, it started working.
I don't know why it failed silently like this and left no trace, this was such a pain to debug.
